# How can I save Windows Event Viewer logs to evtx with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, events

I am trying to save the windows events as an evtx file but I have had no success in doing so.

I have tried several ways but I haven't found a single one that works. I am using PowerShell 7.3.2.
Let's say I only want to get the first 10 events.

```
$logs = Get-WinEvent -LogName Application | Select-Object -First 10
$logs | Export-Xml -Path "test.xml"
```

I have found no way to convert the XML to evtx or directly save the $logs as evtx. Is there some way in converting these xml files to evtx through code/terminal? I would prefer powershell code but I think python could work as well.

Comment: `wevtutil.exe export-log Application "$PWD\test.evtx"` should do the trick

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen can I somehow use a filter that says that no logs older than x days should be saved? By the way thanks for your help! The command worked but I still want to filter because the amount of logs gets really big over time.

Comment: Sure, `wevtutil` has a `/q` switch that allows you to supply an XPath query filter, eg.: `wevtutil epl Application "$PWD\test.evtx" /q:'*[System[and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000]]]'` to only extract events from within the last 864000000 ticks (= 24 hours).

Answer (score -1):

In PowerShell, support for event log cmdlets is limited to `Get-WinEvent`. ([Others are not planned right now.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12575))

You can either use [`wevtutil.exe export-log`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil#parameters) as mentioned in the comments above or you use `CIM` to accomplish this:

```
$backupLogPath = "$env:TEMP\mylog.evtx"
$logfile = Get-CimInstance Win32_NTEventlogFile | Where-Object LogfileName -EQ "Application"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $logfile -MethodName BackupEventLog -Arguments @{ ArchiveFileName = $backupLogPath }
```

*side note: `WMI` exposed `BackupEventlog` directly, `CIM` doesn't do this.*